# socket programming: connect() hangs for a non-existent IP

Tags: c++, sockets, network-programming

Below is the codes to create a socket connection which returns positive socket descriptor if the IP is existent, while it gets stuck in the routine `connect()` if the IP is non-existent:

```
Connection::Connection(string& ip) : sock(0), status(0), conn(0){
    struct sockaddr_in sin;

    sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);//socket() returns -1 on failure.
    sin.sin_family = AF_INET;
    sin.sin_port = htons(22);
    sin.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(ip.c_str());
    cout << "sock: " << sock << endl;
    //fcntl(sock, F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK);
    if(sock != -1){
        conn = connect(sock, (struct sockaddr*)(&sin), sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
        cout << "conn: " << conn << endl;
        if ( conn != 0){
            status = -2;
        }
    }
    else{
        status = -1;
    }
}
```

For debugging purpose, I have put `cout` after `socket()` and `connect()`. And I have tested that `cout << "conn: " << conn << endl;` is never executed and keeps on waiting, if a non-existent IP is supplied to the constructor.

These codes work for an existent IP.

Somewhere I had read that setting `socket descriptor` to `O_NONBLOCK` would solve the hanging problem. Yes, it does but a new issue arises; I could not even connect to an existent IP either.

Please help me in explaining why it is happening and how to solve this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you need to step back and consider what you mean by whether an IP 'exists'.

When you call `connect`, the OS will send a packet (a `SYN` packet) to the destination IP. It has no idea whether the IP 'exists' or not. Indeed that concept is not clearly defined - it might or might not be assigned. The device might or might not be turned on or plugged in. It might be in a DHCP pool where a lease for that IP has or has not been handed out. The OS knows none of this. All the OS knows is whether it gets a reply. And there might be packet loss in either direction which makes it necessary to reply.

Broadly speaking, the OS can get three types of replies (and you can use `tcpdump` or wireshark to see which is happening):

1. The destination IP replies with a `SYN+ACK` packet. This is the next stage of the three way handshake. The destination IP is clearly working.
2. The destination IP replies with an `RST`. That means 'go away'; you'll see 'connection refused'.
3. The destination IP or some intermediate router replies with an ICMP host unreachable or network unreachable, in which case you'll see host unreachable or network unreachable. This is not guaranteed to happen if the host or network is unreachable.

There's a fourth possibility, which is no reply is received at all. In this case `connect` waits and retries a few times, and finally times out. That's what you are seeing. Filtering out ICMP in your firewall will convert case (3) above to this case, but it's important to note this can occur anyway. So this is a natural state of affairs which you should be prepared to handle.

Using a non-blocking `connect()` (by setting `O_NONBLOCK` first) makes `connect()` return immediately - before even a functional IP has set up the connection. In any case, you will need to allow *some* time for a connection to occur. Over a slow link or with packet loss, a functional IP can take tens of seconds to connect. So, in this case you will need to implement your own timeout (for instance by `select()`-ing on the socket). There is (under Linux anyway) no option to set your own timeout to `connect()`, so if you want to change the timeout you have to implement it using a non-blocking connect. Details from Stephens (an excellent book - buy it) on non-blocking `connect()` [here](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=ptSC4LpwGA0C&pg=PA448&lpg=PA448&dq=connect%20non-blocking%20select%20timeout&source=bl&ots=Ks2yMjgoPm&sig=OQJlHwyaVtIOaHSsDj-r38tt17k&hl=en&sa=X&ei=_9K0VNWBMoWy7Qb9moCwCA&ved=0CFAQ6AEwBg#v=onepage&q=connect%20non-blocking%20select%20timeout&f=false).

Comment: Thanks for explaining the behavior nicely. Sorry for my little knowledge. Can I timeout a blocking socket in the above codes I have provided? If Yes. then How?

Comment: Yes, you need to use `select()` to do that. I have amended the last paragraph and put in a link to an example.

Comment: I'll try using `select()`. Thanks for your valuable input :)

Comment: What is the timeout for your fourth case?